# Getting error on invoice details page

Tags: php, magento

I have recently upgraded magento from 1.4.0.1 to 1.7.0.2. Now I am getting error on invoice details page.

Fatal error: Call to a member function updateBackButtonUrl() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento171\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Sales\Order\InvoiceController.php on line 151

The code on line 151 is

```
 $this->getLayout()->getBlock('sales_invoice_view')->updateBackButtonUrl($this->getRequest()->getParam('come_from'));
```

Can anyone help, how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because I have recently updated magneto, there was a chance of being replacement of the controller or view files, So I replaced all the files with the new fresh version but the problem still exists.

Then I found from exception.log file

exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'The requested Payment Method is not available.' in D:\Mage.php:594

as there are many orders and invoices records already in the database, so I assumed that payment methods for these order and invoices may not be installed or may be disabled. So analyzing and comparing with old administrator that two of the payment methods are not recognizing by the system for these orders.

1. Amazon payments.
2. Wired Transfer.

and all order related to this have issue in the detailed page.
Later I found that payments are stored in 'sales_flat_order_payments' table and the field is 'method', But as I see the field it has values.

Then I have done a trick and done some testing order using wired transfer and amazon payments (I have installed a new module for amazon payments), so for wired transfer now I can see the detail page for invoices related to it, so I am sure that it was previously not opening of we have conflicts in database tables related to sales and wired transfer and by doing this transaction the conflicts was resolved

For amazon the value is different for the new order, so I replaced the old values with the new amazon payment value.

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET method='checkoutbyamazon_sandbox' WHERE method='amazonpayments_cba';
```

And now the detail page for all the invoices related to amazon have no errors.

Answer (score 0):

This button works in 1.7x so it is your setup, not a bug in Magento. To work out what is going on:

Check that there are no modules that re-write Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Invoice_View and make sure there are no copies in app/code/local of the InvoiceController.php file.

By 'process of elimination' you can just disable add on modules in app/etc/modules.

Also make sure that the controller file and app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Invoice/View.php are from 1.7x rather than 1.4x.

Comment: I checked no modules are rewriting Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Invoice_View. Also there is no copies of this module in locale and files are from 1.7x

Comment: Also I write this on line 151. var_dump($this->getLayout()->getBlock('sales_invoice_view'));
and it is returning bool(false);